# Beginning model and prime lens

Tags: portrait, prime, photography-basics

I was thinking of buying a Canon EOS Rebel T6 to start of with DSLR. Is it a good option? Previously I have used Canon EOS 1200D and Nikon D3300 from some of my friends. And also should I buy the f/1.8 prime lens simultaneously? I want to click some portraits as well.

Comment: Which f/1.8 prime lens? There are several, including more than one at the 50mm focal length.

Comment: "Is it a good option?" Option for WHAT? Using as a doorstop? (probably a little expensive) For shooting sports for a wire service? For taking landscape photos at sunrise/sunset? For doing product photography? Etc.

Answer (score 1):

The EOS Rebel T6 is a good option considering its low price. It is an entry level DSLR so if you are a beginner it should suit your needs.

Moreover given its low price you can afford to invest in a 1.8 prime lens to complement the kit one(if you are buying it). You will have to choose which focal length you want to have. The first 2 options that come in mind are the 35mm and the 50mm, if you want to shoot portraits the 50mm is obviously better.

Comment: I doubt you'll ever sell a 1.8 prime lens for more than you bought it new (unless the yen goes WAY up against the USD). A lens is an *expense*, not an investment!

Comment: Well it is usually an investment into better photos(if you know how to use it), that is what i meant.